# Errors with Svelte, TypeScript, ESLint, & Prettier Together

Tags: typescript, eslint, svelte, prettier

I'm new to Svelte, but I'm liking it so far. I've written a simple tic-tac-toe app using Svelte & TypeScript to practice with it, and now I'm adding the tooling that I prefer. I normally use a combined eslint/prettier setup, relying on the eslint-plugin-prettier to marry the two together. However, for Svelte, this is not working.

To clarify, ESLint works fine on its own. Prettier works fine on its own. However, when I combine them is when the problem arrises.

**TypeScript**

All of these scenarios use this TypeScript config:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "__sapper__/*", "public/*"]
}
```

**Standalone ESLint**

Here is my `.eslintrc.js` for running eslint standalone:

```
module.exports = {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking'
    ],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020,
        sourceType: 'module',
        tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
        project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
        extraFileExtensions: ['.svelte']
    },
    env: {
        es6: true,
        browser: true
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ['*.svelte'],
            processor: 'svelte3/svelte3'
        }
    ],
    settings: {
        'svelte3/typescript': require('typescript'),
        // ignore style tags in Svelte because of Tailwind CSS
        // See https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3/issues/70
        'svelte3/ignore-styles': () => true
    },
    plugins: ['svelte3', '@typescript-eslint'],
    ignorePatterns: ['node_modules']
};
```

I run it with `eslint --fix './src/**/*.{js,ts,svelte}'` and it works perfectly.

**Standalone Prettier**

Here is my `.prettierrc.js` for running Prettier standalone:

```
module.exports = {
    arrowParens: 'always',
    singleQuote: true,
    printWidth: 90,
    plugins: ['prettier-plugin-svelte'],
    semi: true,
    svelteSortOrder: 'options-styles-scripts-markup',
    svelteStrictMode: false,
    svelteBracketNewLine: true,
    svelteIndentScriptAndStyle: true,
    trailingComma: 'none',
    tabWidth: 4,
    useTabs: true,
    jsxBracketSameLine: false,
    quoteProps: 'as-needed',
    bracketSpacing: true,
    endOfLine: 'lf'
}
```

I run it with `prettier --write ./src` and it works perfectly.

**Combined ESLint & Prettier**

My Prettier config remains the same, here is the modified ESLint config:

```
module.exports = {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
        'plugin:prettier/recommended'
    ],
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaVersion: 2020,
        sourceType: 'module',
        tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
        project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
        extraFileExtensions: ['.svelte']
    },
    env: {
        es6: true,
        browser: true
    },
    overrides: [
        {
            files: ['*.svelte'],
            processor: 'svelte3/svelte3'
        }
    ],
    settings: {
        'svelte3/typescript': require('typescript'),
        // ignore style tags in Svelte because of Tailwind CSS
        // See https://github.com/sveltejs/eslint-plugin-svelte3/issues/70
        'svelte3/ignore-styles': () => true
    },
    plugins: ['svelte3', '@typescript-eslint'],
    ignorePatterns: ['node_modules'],
    rules: {
        'prettier/prettier': ['error', {}, { usePrettierrc: true }],
    }
};
```

I run it with `eslint --fix './src/**/*.{js,ts,svelte}'` and it fails with this error:

```
  2 | import Stats from "./components/Stats.svelte";
  3 |
> 4 | {Board,Stats;}
    |            ^
```

The error is coming from a Svelte component and the import statements in it. Here is what those few lines in the Svelte component looks like. You'll notice that line 4 above doesn't actually exist in my source code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Board from "./components/Board.svelte";
    import Stats from "./components/Stats.svelte";
</script>
```

**Conclusion**

As best I can tell, by the time prettier parses the content it's in a form prettier cannot recognize. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Not helping comment: I’d simply drop eslint. I always feel it fits awkwardly between ts and prettier. Might I ask, what particular feature of eslint that you like but is not covered by ts/prettier?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I encounter the same problem, and after a long time I finally make it out. if you want to integrate `prettier` into `eslint`, just install package `eslint-plugin-prettier`, and make it a plugin in eslint config file.

```js
module.exports = {
   plugins: [ 'prettier'],
}
```

And you must have `svelte-for-vscode` installed, then `prettier/prettier` in
`rules` filed is no longer required.

Besides, after runing`eslint --fix`, you can also continue to run `prettier --write` to format the code using `prettier`.

Hope this answer will make some help to you and others.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is late, but here it is for others that are still stuck on this problem like me:

The problem is that the eslint-plugin-svelte3 and prettier seem to be incompatible.
Ditching eslint-plugin-svelte3 for the [svelte-eslint-parser](https://github.com/ota-meshi/svelte-eslint-parser) and following the recommended typescript setup from the readme is what did the trick for me.

Comment: I fixed this my changing `extends` in my eslint config to `'eslint:recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', 'prettier'` by removing `'plugin:svelte/recommended'`